# Loop through unbounded tracks array in radar_msgs/RadarTrackArray

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am having this programming problem:

```
void msgCallback(const radar_msgs::RadarTrackArray::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  for (int i=0; i < msg->tracks.size(); i++)
   {
      a.push_back(msg->tracks[i].track_id);
   }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ...
  ros::Subscriber radar_sub = nh.subscribe("/radarTrack",1000,msgCallback);
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

the topic "/radarTrack" publishes messages every 20ms and the tracks array is an unbounded array, that is, it gives
different length of array at each frame. For example, msg->tracks.size() can be 420, 28, 128 and so on..
When the length of tracks array is large, the calculation time of for-loop could be larger than 20ms.
In this case, Does the messages that are published by "/radarTrack" wait until the for-loop calculation is complete although its calculation time is larger than 20ms?

Any help will be much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321461/loop-through-unbounded-tracks-array-in-radar_msgs/radartrackarray/) by [roskinetic](https://answers.ros.org/users/37867/roskinetic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2019-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> the topic "/radarTrack" publishes messages every 20ms, [..] When the length of tracks array is large, the calculation time of for-loop could be larger than 20ms. In this case, Does the messages that are published by "/radarTrack" wait until the for-loop calculation is complete although its calculation time is larger than 20ms?

callbacks are not pre-empted, interrupted or run in parallel (with a standard single-threaded spinner as you are using), so if `callback(..)` takes longer than 20 ms to process all the tracks, processing of other messages will be delayed.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roskinetic](https://answers.ros.org/users/37867/roskinetic/) on 2019-04-19**:
Thank you very much! :)